# "413 Request Entity Too Large" when serving Angular web (client side) with Nginx

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, amazon-eks

This is my first question ever.
Thanks in advance for your help.

I've been working on a web (**ANGULAR**) whice comunicates with my backend (**NODE JS)**
Everything works fine when serving it with **angularCli** (*ng serve*...)

It's deploy time and now i have to put them on different dockers which would be scaled using Amazon EKS service. So following the good practices i moved from serving it with angularCli to nginx

All is working fine except for one service where users have to attach some PDF files.
It responds: "*413 Request Entity Too Large - nginx*"

I understand what that response error means... but my question is why is NGINX cheking/controlling the size of the users requests if angular is running in client side?

I would expect thtat kind of response comming from the NODE JS backend, not the "web serving tool"

Expected behaviour:  Browser http request -> NodeJs

is this happening? =>  Browser http request -> NGINX? -> NodeJS

Does hosting services inform the browsers how much all requests in the served web could be?
Or maybe... this response isn't comming from the NGINX inside the web container, but from another NGNIX involved with some AWS.EKS or "whatever infraestructure stuff"?

Comment: "*why is NGINX cheking/controlling the size of the users requests if angular is running in client side?*" well, presumably this is sent over the network. If it really was just on the client-side then nginx wouldn't be involved. Nor would there be an HTTP response code if there was no HTTP request.

Comment: "*Browser -> NodeJs (expected) Browser -> NGINX? -> NodeJS*" what? Node runs *on the server*. There is no direct link to the browser. Moreover, why would Node show up *twice* on the route? It's just Browser -> nginx -> Node with nginx sitting between the two. There might be more things on this route (e.g., load balancers, proxies, etc) but it won't change this topology. It would just add more things on either side of nginx.